# Extra directories and files added to git repository

Tags: macos, git, github, bitbucket

I had always used Git locally on Mac OSX and decided to try out Github and Bitbucket. I had some issues getting it working and tried a few fixes that others suggested who had similar problems. I was able to push to Github and Bitbucket, but I also managed to somehow add extra directories and files to my repository in the process.

I'm using Xampp to develop locally, and I have a folder in there that I created my repository with, so the file structure is something like this

```
Applications
   XAMPP  
      xamppfiles
         htdocs
            myproject      -this is was originally the repository that I had been using
            randomdirectory1
            randomdirectory2
            randomdirectory3
            randomfile1
            randomfile2
```

One thing to note. Not every single directory and file in htdocs was added to my repository. There were only 3 added, and about 7 other folders.

Prior to trying out github my repository just consisted of myproject located in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myproject. Now, there are a bunch of other directories and files added to it. I know this, because in conjunction with the command line I also used GitX for a visual reference. Now, all of these extra files and directories are showing up.

Maybe I don't fully understand how git repositories works. Prior to this, I had only used add, commit and checkout commands. All I know is that my repository appears to be different in GitX and matches on Bitbucket/Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What folder did you initialize the Git repo from?  It sounds like you meant to init from the myproject folder, but instead you did it from the Applications folder.
- Does GitHub show all those extra directories?
- Where is the hidden .git folder?
- Is this a private repo just for you, or just for you and a few known others?  Are you willing to rewrite history?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure I was in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myproject when I initialized, otherwise there are even more files and directories that would have been added. Yes, these extra files are shown in Github/bitbucket. It is a private repo on bitbucket (I removed it from github), on the website itself.

Comment: I think I would need to see the repo to give more specific help.  Otherwise, maybe you can just delete the hidden .git folder and start over with the repo.

Comment: I'm ok with that. I made a backup of my hdtocs on an external hard drive, so I'll still have the repo (a backup of it, I suppose), right? Regardless, I periodically back up my directory onto a hard drive just in case anything happens. How do I locate the hidden .git file?

Comment: It's a folder, not a file.  If you're okay with losing all your project history (not the project itself, just the history), then here are a few ways to show hidden files in OS X: http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/

Once you find it, delete it.

Comment: I took a closer look and noticed that on the extra directories, it's says "This is a tree with path directory_name_here". Does that mean anything worthwhile?